# Using KnexJS to query X number of tables?

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, promise, knex.js

I have a unique situation here which I am having trouble solving in an elegant fashion.

A user passes up an array of signals which they want to export data for.  This array can be 1 -> Any_Number so first I go fetch the table names (each signal stores data in a separate table) based on the signals passed and store those in an object.

The next step is to iterate over that object (which contains the table names I need to query), execute the query per table and store the results in an object which will be passed to next chain in the Promise.  I haven't seen any examples online of good ways to handle this but I know it's a fairly unique scenario.

My code prior to attempting to add support for arrays of signals was simply the following:

```
exports.getRawDataForExport = function(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var getTableName = function() {
      return knex('monitored_parameter')
        .where('device_id', data.device_id)
        .andWhere('internal_name', data.param)
        .first()
        .then(function(row) {
          if(row) {
            var resp = {"table" : 'monitored_parameter_data_' + row.id, "param" : row.display_name};
            return resp;
          }
        });
    }

    var getData = function(runningResult) {
      return knexHistory(runningResult.table)
        .select('data_value as value', 'unit', 'created')
        .then(function(rows) {
          runningResult.data = rows;
          return runningResult;
        });
    }

    var createFile = function(runningResult) {

      var fields = ['value', 'unit', 'created'],
          csvFileName = filePathExport + runningResult.param + '_export.csv',
          zipFileName = filePathExport + runningResult.param + '_export.gz';

      var csv = json2csv({data : runningResult.data, fields : fields, doubleQuotes : ''});

      fs.writeFileSync(csvFileName, csv);

      // create streams for gZipping
      var input = fs.createReadStream(csvFileName);
      var output = fs.createWriteStream(zipFileName);

      // gZip
      input.pipe(gzip).pipe(output);

      return zipFileName;

    }

    getTableName()
      .then(getData)
      .then(createFile)
      .then(function(zipFile) {
        resolve(zipFile);
      });
  });
}
```

Obviously that works fine for a single table and I have gotten the getTableName() and createFile() methods updated to handle arrays of data so this question only pertains to the getData() method.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of problem is far from unique and, approached the right way, is very simply solved.

**Don't rewrite any of the three internal functions.**

Just purge the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) from `.getRawDataForExport()` such that it returns a naturally occurring promise and propagates asynchronous errors to the caller.

```
return getTableName()
.then(getData)
.then(createFile);
```

Now, `.getRawDataForExport()` is the basic building-block for your multiple "gets".

Then, a design choice; parallel versus sequential operations. Both are very well documented.

Parallel:

```
exports.getMultiple = function(arrayOfSignals) {
    return Promise.all(arrayOfSignals.map(getRawDataForExport));
};
```

Sequential:

```
exports.getMultiple = function(arrayOfSignals) {
    return arrayOfSignals.reduce(function(promise, signal) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            return getRawDataForExport(signal);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
};
```

In the first instance, for best potential performance, try parallel.

If the server chokes, or is likely ever to choke, on parallel operations, choose sequential.

Comment: This is great advice and I feel like it could open up entirely new doors for me in terms of handling these types of events in JS...  That said, could you elaborate a little more on the first things you mention? A short example showing how to break the antipattern and where the resolve/reject happen would be helpful.

The way I saw it, .getRawDataForExport() was already returning a Promise, is that not the case? Thanks again!

Comment: @NicholasKreidberg, sorry my bad. You were indeed already returning a promise. Edited words should make more sense.